# Lucene Query in Order

Tags: java, lucene

I have created lucene in java index and able to do searching. Now I want my query in such as way that it maintains order. Say for example I have following in my index

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 1
1 2 4 3 1
1 3 2 4 1
```

And my query is `1 3 4` then it should give result like :

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 1
1 3 2 4 1
1 2 4 3 1
```

Hope question is clear.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [span query](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_2_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/package-summary.html) to find terms that are in close proximity and are in specific order. The ordering condition can be relaxed. An excellent article on spans can be found [here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/07/18/the-spanquery/).

Comment: This looks good to me. Still need a way to crate query : Initial I was using " Query q1 = new Query(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, "Id", analyzer).parse(dis.readLine());" If I use SpanQuery query will be something like "SpanNearQuery q = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] { new SpanTermQuery(new Term("Id","1")),new SpanTermQuery(new Term("Id", "2"))},5000,  true);". How can I parse the query in one go from file. My query will be of lengths like " 1 2 3" or " 1 3 4 5" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a BooleanQuery and be sure to call [`setAllowDocsOutOfOrder(true)`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html#setAllowDocsOutOfOrder%28boolean%29).  If your index is ordered by docid, this should restrict the documents from becoming disordered.

**Edit:**
You could also use the [`Sort`](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Sort.html) class to order a search by index or relevance.  This looks more useful as you can use any Query type in your search.

Comment: when I use setAllowDocsOutOfOrder(true), it is giving can't find symbol. what am I missing ? Also how sort is useful here my query can be 1 4 3 also & in that case last retrieved i.e. 1 2 4 3 1
should come 1st.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question.  Now it seems as if you want the hits be be sorted in a way that term by term before-relations in the documents match the term order in the query.  I had thought you meant order by document id would be preserved.  That sounds like you should define your own custom scoring method.